# "App.CallbackHandler" does not implement interface member - c#

Tags: c#

I am implementing a WCF service and client application.

1. There is a client class:

   ```
   private class CallbackHandler : ServiceReference1.IStockQuoteServiceCallback
   {
       public async Task SendQuoteAsync(string code, double value)
       {
           Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1:f2}", code, value);
       }
   }
   ```
2. And the Service interface class:

   ```
   public interface IStockQuoteCallback
   {
       [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
       Task SendQuote(string code, double value);
   }
   ```

I don't know why it says

> 'App.Program.CallbackHandler' does not implement interface member 'App.ServiceReference1.IStockQuoteServiceCallback.SendQuote(string, double)'

There is the Service Reference concerning the above code:

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
    [System.ServiceModel.ServiceContractAttribute(ConfigurationName="ServiceReference1.IStockQuoteService", CallbackContract=typeof(WSWCF_pretest_android.ServiceReference1.IStockQuoteServiceCallback))]
public interface IStockQuoteService {

    [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(IsOneWay=true, Action="http://tempuri.org/IStockQuoteService/StartSendingQuotes")]
    void StartSendingQuotes();

    [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(IsOneWay=true, Action="http://tempuri.org/IStockQuoteService/StartSendingQuotes")]
    System.Threading.Tasks.Task StartSendingQuotesAsync();
}

public interface IStockQuoteServiceCallback {

    [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(IsOneWay=true, Action="http://tempuri.org/IStockQuoteService/SendQuote")]
    void SendQuote(string code, double value);
}
```

The method signatures should be identical.

Any suggestions?

Comment: The interfaces are also different. IStockQuoteServiceCallback vs IStockQuoteCallback

Comment: But if I rename the `ServiceReference1.IStockQuoteServiceCallback` to `ServiceReference1.IStockQuoteCallback` it doesn't find the type...

Comment: Are you *sure* `IStockQuoteCallback` is defined in `ServiceReference1`?

Comment: I guess it is. I posted the namespace reference above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The method signatures are identical.

Nope, no they are not.

Your interface has a method called `SendQuote`, but your class has a method named `SendQuoteAsync`.

You need to have them both have the same name, either both `SendQuoteAsync` or both `SendQuote`.

In addition ([thanks tnw](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26103921/app-callbackhandler-does-not-implement-interface-member-c-sharp#comment40907818_26103921)), the interface you posted is not the same as the implimented interface in your class. `IStockQuoteCallback` is the name of the interface, but you are implementing `IStockQuoteServiceCallback`.

Fixing those should fix or reduce your errors.

---

You seem to be confusing the two interfaces you have. For reference, these are the interfaces you have posted:

```
public interface IStockQuoteCallback
{
    Task SendQuote(string code, double value);
}

public interface IStockQuoteServiceCallback 
{
    void SendQuote(string code, double value);
}
```

One returns a `Task`. The other returns `void`. You need to pick one interface to use and return the correct data type.

---

The last problem you have is that you are trying to make the method async, when the method is *not* async. The method signatures must match, even with this keyword. So this:

```
public async Task QuoteAsync(string code, double value)
```

is not the same as

```
public Task SendQuote(string code, double value)
```

Either you have to change the interface, or you are stuck making the implemented method non-async.

Comment: It just generates a new error `'WSWCF_pretest_android.Program.CallbackHandler' does not implement interface member 'WSWCF_pretest_android.ServiceReference1.IStockQuoteCallback.SendQuote(string, double)'. 'WSWCF_pretest_android.Program.CallbackHandler.SendQuote(string, double)' cannot implement 'WSWCF_pretest_android.ServiceReference1.IStockQuoteCallback.SendQuote(string, double)' because it does not have the matching return type of 'void'.` :/

Comment: Ok, well the interface `IStockQuoteCallback` has `SendQuote` returning a `Task`, but your error says that it really returns `void`. So which interface do you want to use? One returns a `Task`, the other does not.

Comment: Well I now took Task, but now it says again `'WSWCF_pretest_android.Program.CallbackHandler' does not implement interface member 'WSWCF_pretest_android.ServiceReference1.IStockQuoteServiceCallback.SendQuote(string, double)'`
What should I change here? Btw it's an example from MSDN and I don't know either why I should use an async Task if I only run one function at one time.

Comment: Right, that makes sense. If I remove async it turns out another error (I think it doesn't want me to succeed ..) `'WSWCF_pretest_android.Program.CallbackHandler.SendQuote(string, double)': not all code paths return a value`

Comment: That's fine, it just means that not all paths in your method return a value. Nothing about this problem. But your original question should be solved now.

Comment: Thanks for helping me. But this error holds me back from debugging it. What does this mean for me? Where should it return values?

Comment: Please ask a new question about this, or ping me from chat. Keep threads to "one question per thread".

Comment: Of course I will. But for now I solved the whole problem. The cause for newer exceptions was a wrong generated endpoint address. The Service Reference was also generated with errors causing the confusion with the different data types void/Task. I now corrected that and the endpoint address (it took the local server domain address) and it works! Thank you again!